# If else with 5 possible cases PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have bunch of records in Database and i have been searching for query on NULL json object and i got that right,but now its difficult for me to continue it on 5 possible cases

For example: am showing data on basis of 5 cases and 3 attributes

```
config->'external_http_port' , config->'external_host' , config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'
```

cases are

1: `config->'external_http_port'` can be null

2: `config->'external_host'` can be null

3: `config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'` can be null

4: All three can be null

5: two of three can be null.

for just checking all three nulls i am doing query as

```
select * from cameras where (config->'external_http_port') is null and (config->'external_host') is null and (config->'snapshots'->>'jpg') is null
```

any help will be appreciated

Using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: So you want all rows that at least one of the three is null?

Comment: Cross-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34430421/398670

Comment: no i want all rows where 1 can be null, 2 can bull and 3 can be null and 3 arent null @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ

Comment: But your  case 4 says all three can be null? Are these 5 case you have separate queries? Or one query?

Comment: i said the same thing, 3 can be null and 3 can be present as well.

Comment: i tries one case and it gives me error `IF (config->'external_http_port') is null
 SELECT * FROM cameras WHERE (config->> 'external_host' = '82.58.192.201' and config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' = '/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2')`

Comment: I ask again: do you need one query or five, one for each case?

Comment: i need solution where it is with 5 cases or with one, but it should fulfill 5 conditions! like you can say one query which fulfill 5 conditions, like one null, 2 null, 3 null, 3 present. and there are 3 attributes , confusing me

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data.

Comment: output will be * in every case but those are just conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the long comments, it's still not clear if you need one query for each case or a single query that includes all five of them. So, we'll take them separately:

1. `config->'external_http_port'` is null

   ```
   select * from cameras 
   where config->'external_http_port' is null ;
   ```
2. `config->'external_host'` is null
   (omitting the select):

   ```
   where config->'external_host' is null ;
   ```
3. `config->'snapshots'->>'jpg'` is null

   ```
   where config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' is null ;
   ```
4. all three are null (you got that right!):

   ```
   where config->'external_http_port' is null 
     and config->'external_host' is null 
     and config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' is null ;
   ```
5. two out of three are are null (and the third isn't)

   ```
   where (config->'external_http_port' is null)::int
         + (config->'external_host' is null)::int 
         + (config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' is null)::int 
         = 2 ;
   ```

And if you want all five cases in one query, i.e. any of the five conditions to hold, this can be written (using a complicated condition, similar to the 5th case above):

```
    where (config->'external_http_port' is null)::int
          + (config->'external_host' is null)::int 
          + (config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' is null)::int 
          >= 1 ;
```

or more simply:

```
    where config->'external_http_port' is null 
       or config->'external_host' is null 
       or config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' is null ;
```

Comment: where to put equality? as am doing this `IF (config->'external_http_port') is null
 SELECT * FROM cameras WHERE (config->> 'external_host' = '82.58.192.201' and config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' = '/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2')`

Comment: Don't use `IF`. Use `WHERE`. `SELECT * FROM cameras WHERE (config->'external_http_port' is null) and (config->> 'external_host' = '82.58.192.201' and config->'snapshots'->>'jpg' = '/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=snapPicture2') `